# Checking if nested Keys exist in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am working with a sports API for baseball. I am having issues checking to see if:

```
outcome.runners[0]
```

or

```
outcome.runners[1]
```

or

```
outcome.runners[2]
```

exists or not. I can check to see if the **runners** node exists by doing

```
outcome.hasOwnProperty('runners')===true
```

but have issues seeing if the first second or third runner is there( also has own property is not my ideal method to use). This matters because if only one runner is on base the node

```
outcome.runners[1] and outcome.runners[2]
```

will not populate and I will be checking something that doesn't exist, and end up getting an error. Below is some lean JSON to give an idea of what I am looking through.

```
{
  "outcome": {
    "-type": "pitch",
    "-current_inning": "3",
    "-current_inning_half": "T",
    "runners": {
      "runner": [
        {
          "-id": "ca159e78-05a9-410a-be7b-3ebad5496a88",
          "-last_name": "John",
        },
        {
          "-id": "3742039b-7c2a-4f75-be72-d4478ed83a58",
          "-last_name": "Smith",
        },

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it'd be great if you also provide your JS code so we can see what you tried :)

Comment: How about `Array.isArray(outcome.runners.runner) && outcome.runners.runner.length > 1`

Comment: What does the data structure look like if there's only one runner?

Comment: Since *runner* is an array that doesn't seem to have any elided members, you can simply do `runner.length` to see how many runners there are (noting that length is zero indexed so length 2 means there are runners at 0 and 1).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided example JSON, none of these are actually correctly pointing to your runner objects:
`outcome.runners[0]
outcome.runners[1]
outcome.runners[2]`

According to your data structure your runners can be accessed through the property: `outcome.runners.runner`

So to get runner #1, you would do:
`outcome.runners.runner[0]`

In Javascript, in order to check if an element at a specific index exists in your array, you can use a simple if statement:
`if (array[index]) {
 //do stuff here
}`

In your case to check if runner #1 exists, you can do:
`if (outcome.runners.runner[0]) {
 //do stuff here
}`

p.s. The extra level of hierarchy introduced by having a 'runner' property of the 'runners' property in your data structure could and should be eliminated, as it creates unnecessary complexity and makes no sense.

Your data should look more like this:

```
{
  "outcome": {
    "-type": "pitch",
    "-current_inning": "3",
    "-current_inning_half": "T",
    "runners": [
        {
          "-id": "ca159e78-05a9-410a-be7b-3ebad5496a88",
          "-last_name": "John",
        },
        {
          "-id": "3742039b-7c2a-4f75-be72-d4478ed83a58",
          "-last_name": "Smith",
        },

    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are most welcome. Please accept and upvote if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

**observation :** JSON provided by you is not a valid JSON.

[image]

You have to remove the `,` from the last property of an object.

**Valid JSON :**[image]

Related to parse the JSON, as [matetukacs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3942694/matetukacs) suggest.As per your data structure your runners can be accessed through the property: `outcome.runners.runner`